# Why does SharePoint create a "Workflow Users" group automatically?

Tags: workflow, groups

Why does SharePoint create a 'Workflow Users' group automatically? I've noticed that this group doesn't appear when any workflow is created, it's only created when a specific type of workflow is created. Does anyone know what circumstances triggers this group to be created by SharePoint?

Comment: What happens if I delete those groups?

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of google-fu gave me the answer:

We discovered that the cause is the 'Add Permissions' action in SharePoint designer.  It does this to ensure users have 'Limited Access' permissions to the parent library, site, etc.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9dcdbef-0401-4268-9b2a-a3490379641b/what-prompts-sharepoint-to-create-a-sitename-workflow-users-group-automatically?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Comment: Do you know how 'Add Permissions' action is activated? What Condition / Action? As 'Add permission' is not a default action in SharePoint designer.

Comment: 'Add Permissions' is a Standard Action. It is only available inside a 'User-Impersonation Step'